# React re-render on IE 11

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mobx, mobx-react

We are developing an interface in wich we use React and Mobx.
We have a component to activate the user account with a
link and a code that are sent to the user's email:

https://mysite/activate?Code=6bgoh9n0uk7a84lc3s9e2lso5j

In the component we call the backend to verify that the code is valid and activate the user.
In case of being valid, the backend returns the user and his token.
This token is stored in the localStorage and then we redirect to the main dashboard:

```
axios.get(`/user/activate/${code}`)
.then(action(response => {
   window.localStorage.setItem("myToken", JSON.stringify(response.data));
   window.location.href = "/dashboard";
}))
.catch(action(error => {
    console.log(error);
}));
```

In Chrome and Mozilla Firefox the redirection is successful, but in IE 11 and Edge Browser the component is rendered again, which causes the code to be checked against the backendand we indicate on the screen that the code is no longer valid.

What are we doing wrong?

Comment: Try to use `history.pushState({}, 'dashboard', '/dashboard')` instead of `location.href = '/dashboard'`

Comment: @Freez this only works if they have client side routing.

Comment: Can you post the code of the component/container that renders in your `/dashboard` route? I am curious to see if maybe setting the attribute in localStorage is buggy in IE/Edge and is causing a redirect back to the page that dispatches the axios get. Can you confirm with a `console.log` that the localStorage attribute `'myToken'` is being set for sure in IE and Edge?

Comment: Are there any javascript errors?

Comment: @Freez, You were right, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need a polyfill for `Promise` in IE11. More details over here:
https://github.com/mzabriskie/axios/blob/master/UPGRADE_GUIDE.md#es6-promise-polyfill